# UIView becomes transparent during and after applying 3d transform

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

After searching and reading through apple documentation, I have decided to ask the experts out there for help. I have add animation to my simple uiview to rate it like french door outwards. It works file, but the view during the animation and after is becoming transparent. When I do the same with 2D animations, the view stays opaque.

How can I keep the views background opaque? Do I need to set additional .mxx values in addition to .m34 perspective

My code is below :

```
{

 [self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(1.5,0.5) forView:mainView];
...

 [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                     animations: 
^{
CATransform3D leftTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                         leftTransform.m34 = -1.0f/500; //dark magic to set the 3D perspective
                         leftTransform = CATransform3DRotate(leftTransform, - M_PI_2/2.2, 0, 1, 0);                        
                         mainView.layer.transform = leftTransform;
 }

                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             ...
                        }
                     }];
}
```

Comment: I was able to resolve it myself. It turned out to be zposition that made the background view positions itself infront of my main view that I was applying 3d animation rotation to. Once I set the Z position correctly, the views behaved as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the zposition to a large enough value so that, the view that got rotated stays above it in the hierarchy.

In the above code, insert this code

```
mainView.layer.zPosition = -600;
```

That will fix the animation.